# UE4 Multiplayer how to replicate Player name in lobby

Tags: c++, multiplayer, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I've been working on a little 1V1 snipper project to try and get a better grip on the replication and the game framework of unreal engine.

So after the core gameplay, I'm trying to make a lobby system. I've been able to make the player join together without any issues, but I struggle a little bit with the replication. I'm trying to show the player's name over their pawn in the lobby, and I can't get it to work. In the client, both their name doesn't get replicated, and in the server, only the server name appear:

[image: Client Lobby]
[image: Server lobby]

And I get this error from the server logs

```
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:318][906]PIE: Error: Only Local Player Controllers can be assigned to widgets. BP_PlayerLobbyController_C_1 is not a Local Player Controller.
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:321][906]LogScript: Warning: Accessed None trying to read property CallFunc_Create_ReturnValue
        BP_PlayerLobbyController_C /Game/Maps/Lobby.Lobby:PersistentLevel.BP_PlayerLobbyController_C_1
        Function /Game/Player/Controller/BP_PlayerLobbyController.BP_PlayerLobbyController_C:ExecuteUbergraph_BP_PlayerLobbyController:0049
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:323][906]LogScript: Warning: Script call stack:
        Function /Game/Player/Controller/BP_PlayerLobbyController.BP_PlayerLobbyController_C:ReceiveBeginPlay
        Function /Game/Player/Controller/BP_PlayerLobbyController.BP_PlayerLobbyController_C:ExecuteUbergraph_BP_PlayerLobbyController

[2020.01.21-00.45.03:325][906]LogOnlineSession: Warning: OSS: No game present to join for session (GameSession)
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:326][906]LogTemp: POST LOGIN FOR
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:331][906]LogScript: Warning: Accessed None trying to read property CallFunc_GetController_ReturnValue
        BP_Character_Lobby_C /Game/Maps/Lobby.Lobby:PersistentLevel.BP_Character_Lobby_C_1
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:Display Player Name:00CC
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:333][906]LogScript: Warning: Script call stack:
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:ReceiveBeginPlay
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:ExecuteUbergraph_BP_Character_Lobby
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:Display Player Name

[2020.01.21-00.45.03:335][906]LogScript: Warning: Accessed None
        BP_Character_Lobby_C /Game/Maps/Lobby.Lobby:PersistentLevel.BP_Character_Lobby_C_1
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:Display Player Name:00E1
[2020.01.21-00.45.03:337][906]LogScript: Warning: Script call stack:
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:ReceiveBeginPlay
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:ExecuteUbergraph_BP_Character_Lobby
        Function /Game/Player/Character/BP_Character_Lobby.BP_Character_Lobby_C:Display Player Name
```

So I get that something is wrong with accessing the 2nd player controller from bluprint like this
[image]

But I don't know how to make it work other wise. I've set the PlayerName widget to replicated, but it doesn't seem to work.
[image]

Any idea on how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PlayerControllers for all players exist only on the server. 
Each client only has its own PlayerController, but none of the others.

Calling GetController on a pawn will only work if you're on the server or if the pawn is locally controlled. Instead, get the PlayerState from the pawn directly.

Widgets exist *only* on each client, they can not and should not be replicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I somehow though it would be different because it was attach to a Widget Component!